# How to get the lowest value of second item in key list of dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key, key-value

Suppose we have a dictionary like this:

```
Dict={'2020-12-23_36.JPG': [2959, 4690],
 '2020-12-28_106.JPG': [2956, 4592],
 '2020-12-28_117.JPG': [2993, 4752],
 '2020-12-28_13.JPG': [2919, 4921],
 '2020-12-28_141.JPG': [2984, 4944]}
```

How do we retrieve from this the key with the lowest value of the second item in the list?:

```
import operator
min(Dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
"2020-12-28_13.JPG"
```

This makes sense as "2020-12-28_13.JPG" does indeed have the lowest value in the first item of the list: 2919

I attempted the following but with no success:

```
min(Dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[1][1]
"4921"
```

It only prints the second item of the list, but based on the first item of the list.

I also tried:

```
min(Dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[1])[0]
"TypeError: 'operator.itemgetter' object is not subscriptable"
```

Expected result

```
min(Dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[1][1]
'2020-12-28_106.JPG' #(because 4592 is the lowest value of the -1 in list)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might actually be very simple. sorted sorts based on any "key" for any iterable. In the instant case, the key is the 2nd item in the value of the dictionary.

```
sorted(Dict, key = lambda x: Dict[x][1])[0]
```

Comment: Thanks! to make it complete, could you change the answer to: sorted(Dict, key = lambda x: Dict[x][1])[0]

Answer (score 1):

You have small typo bug on you code, compare this:

Your line

```
min(Dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)[1])[0]
```

Correct one

```
min(Dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[1][0]
```